# Cancellation law for sum of ideals

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals

Let $R$ be a local regular ring (for example, the ring of formal power series) and let $I,J,\mathfrak{a} \subsetneq R$ be ideals such that $I+\mathfrak{a}=J+\mathfrak{a}$.

Under which condition can I conclude that $I=J$?

Comment: There is no reasonable condition: think of the case where $\frak a$ is the maximal ideal and $I,J\neq R$ are arbitrary. That $R$ is regular is completely irrelevant.